# How to use add and access data in LocalStorage in Gatsby

Tags: local-storage, gatsby

I have a Gatsby app where I am creating a little shopping cart. In order to make the data persist whenever a user clicks on add to cart, I want to use local storage. I use the below code for this

```
import React from 'react';

export default function OrderItem() {
    const addToCart = (selectedItem) => {
        localStorage.setItem('cartItems', selectedItem);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={addToCart}>Add </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But this gives me a localStorage.setItem is not a function error.

Anyone have any idea on why this might be happening?

Comment: What is selectedItem?

Comment: How are you using it?

Comment: added the minimum code to replicate this issue

Comment: You are not passing any `selectedItem` to your `addToCart` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localStorage.setItem is not a function` means that you do have a `localStorage` object, but that object in turn doesn't have a `setItem`. That should never be able to happen in a browser.

Gatsby will not modify `localStorage` either. So the most likely problem is that you've declared another variable called `localStorage` that is overriding the one by the browser.

Try doing a `console.log(localStorage)` in your code. You should see something like this in Chrome. If you don't, you likely have another variable in scope with that name.

[image]

Comment: Thanks buddy! I had infact used localStorage earlier and this was the issue. made a huge mental note to not use reserved terms such as this!